# DPMS & PowerSave on laptop

Tags: power-management, bspwm, dpms

I have an HP PowerBook 440 G4 with Debian Bullseye & BSWPM installed.
My locker is `lightdm` with `slick-greeter` without a screensaver.

My `xset q` says:

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

I installed `xfce4-power-manager` in order to put my laptop in suspend mode after a certain period of time, but it only turned off my monitor. I get this by default without the power manager.

So, I want to suspend my laptop after a certain amount of inactivity, as I can get with a power manager in a desktop environment, i.e. `after X minutes on battery` and `after X minutes on AC`.

How can I achieve this?